# NullPayload vs null check

Tags: mule, mule-el

According to the following ticket: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6427 For NullPayload I should be able to use :

```
<when expression="#[payload == null]">
```

but that doesn't work. It fails. I am using Mule 3.5.1

Here is an example flow:

```
<flow name="testNull">
        <poll frequency="10000">
            <logger />
        </poll>

        <set-payload value="#[org.mule.transport.NullPayload.getInstance()]" />

        <choice>
            <when expression="#[payload == null]">
                <logger level="ERROR" message="NullPayload is same as null" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger level="ERROR" message="Doesnt work" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>

    </flow>
```

This will always print 'Doesn't work'. However message.payload == null works. Whats the difference between "payload" and "message.payload"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `#[payload]` alias. Use the real thing and it will work: `#[message.payload]`.

Comment: Also I created the following issue to track the problem: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8217

Comment: noticed this before also. "payload" never goes through the MessageContext where the null conversion happens. Did a quick fix locally. Will commit and raise a pr.